# Asp.Net TextBox (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, webforms

On my website I am having a text-box and I want to give it this type of functionality:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/input-prompt-text/

On the above website javascript code is given but how can I actually combine it with my asp.net text-box server control. Also the initial text which I want to assign it will be coming from code behind.

Comment: Also, make sure jQuery is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the title on your textbox like this:

```
myTextBox.Attributes["Title"] = "The Watermark Goes Here!";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will give your approach a shot and see if it works out.

Comment: Hi Blankasaurus, sorry for late reply. Yes it worked perfectly. Thanks for your time.